# Getting exception when using getCryptoRandom method of CryptoRandomFactory class. Apache-commons-crypto library

Tags: java, apache-commons

I'm trying to use Apache Commons Crypto library. I'm using example code from apache official site for using Random API of this lib.
Here is the link to it - https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-crypto/xref-test/org/apache/commons/crypto/examples/RandomExample.html

And I get this exception when using method getCryptoRandom.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.security.GeneralSecurityException: CryptoRandom: [org.apache.commons.crypto.random.OpenSslCryptoRandom] failed with java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at org.apache.commons.crypto.random.CryptoRandomFactory.getCryptoRandom(CryptoRandomFactory.java:217)
    at com.nix.apps.crypto.Main.main(Main.java:25)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at org.apache.commons.crypto.utils.ReflectionUtils.newInstance(ReflectionUtils.java:90)
    at org.apache.commons.crypto.random.CryptoRandomFactory.getCryptoRandom(CryptoRandomFactory.java:198)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.apache.commons.crypto.utils.ReflectionUtils.newInstance(ReflectionUtils.java:88)
    ... 2 more
Caused by: java.security.GeneralSecurityException: Native library could not be initialised
    at org.apache.commons.crypto.random.OpenSslCryptoRandom.<init>(OpenSslCryptoRandom.java:88)
    ... 7 more
Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: ENGINE_load_rdrand
    at org.apache.commons.crypto.random.OpenSslCryptoRandomNative.initSR(Native Method)
    at org.apache.commons.crypto.random.OpenSslCryptoRandom.<clinit>(OpenSslCryptoRandom.java:56)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
    at org.apache.commons.crypto.utils.ReflectionUtils.getClassByNameOrNull(ReflectionUtils.java:138)
    at org.apache.commons.crypto.utils.ReflectionUtils.getClassByName(ReflectionUtils.java:103)
    at org.apache.commons.crypto.random.CryptoRandomFactory.getCryptoRandom(CryptoRandomFactory.java:197)
    ... 1 more
```

Process finished with exit code 1

How to solve this issue?

As far as I understand the proble is with loading openSSL engine or something like that:

```
Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: ENGINE_load_rdrand
    at org.apache.commons.crypto.random.OpenSslCryptoRandomNative.initSR(Native Method)
    at org.apache.commons.crypto.random.OpenSslCryptoRandom.<clinit>(OpenSslCryptoRandom.java:56)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
    at org.apache.commons.crypto.utils.ReflectionUtils.getClassByNameOrNull(ReflectionUtils.java:138)
    at org.apache.commons.crypto.utils.ReflectionUtils.getClassByName(ReflectionUtils.java:103)
    at org.apache.commons.crypto.random.CryptoRandomFactory.getCryptoRandom(CryptoRandomFactory.java:197)
```

Comment: I receive the same exact error.
Usage:

 PROPS.setProperty(CryptoRandomFactory.CLASSES_KEY, CryptoRandomFactory.RandomProvider.OPENSSL.getClassName());
CryptoRandom random = CryptoRandomFactory.getCryptoRandom(PROPS);

Comment: I fixed my issue

PROPS.setProperty(CryptoRandomFactory.CLASSES_KEY, CryptoRandomFactory.RandomProvider.OPENSSL.getClassName());
        PROPS.setProperty(CryptoCipherFactory.CLASSES_KEY, CryptoCipherFactory.CipherProvider.OPENSSL.getClassName());
        CryptoRandom random = CryptoRandomFactory.getCryptoRandom(PROPS);

Comment: it seems the factory not only need the random provider, it also needs the cipher provider.